# Android Notifications not showing up in one device

Tags: android, android-notifications

The notification appears in 2 devices(Xiaomi, Vivo) both >26 SDK. But it doesnt show up on my Samsung device which is also >26.

This is how i implemented the notification

```
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager1;

public void CreateMessage(String name,String message, Context context){
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Activity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int notificationNumber = prefs.getInt("notificationNumber", 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Finderr_channel_id1");

        mNotificationManager1 =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            String channelId1 = "Finderr_channel_id1";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId1,
                    "Finderr Message",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            mNotificationManager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId1);
        }


        Intent ii = new Intent(context, NotificationHandler.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, ii, 0);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigText.bigText(name + " sent you a message!");
        bigText.setBigContentTitle(name);
        bigText.setSummaryText(message);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_small);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(name);
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);

        mNotificationManager1.notify(notificationNumber, mBuilder.build());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        notificationNumber++;
        editor.putInt("notificationNumber", notificationNumber);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

I have used shared-preferences to track count of my notifications, so that every message stacks up with previous one. Although, not even 1 notification shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many times do you call CreateMessage method?
This code is suppose to be called only once for your application:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            String channelId1 = "Finderr_channel_id1";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId1,
                    "Finderr Message",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            mNotificationManager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId1);
        }
```

Also I can say that i had some problems with Samsung devices when my app tried to start foreground service with permanent notification. See dontkillmyapp.com for details